# How many cows will eat the field?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Three pasture fields have areas of $\frac{10}{3}$, $10$ and $24$ acres, respectively. The fields initially are covered with grass of the same thickness and new grass grows on each at the same rate per acre. If $12$ cows eat the first field bare in $4$ weeks and $21$ cows eat the second field bare in $9$ weeks, how many cows will eat the third field bare in $18$ weeks? Assume that all cows eat at the same rate.

I set up a system of equations where $T =$ thickness, $g =$ rate at which grass grows back per week, $x_1 =$ rate at which cows eat per week, $x =$number of cows that will eat the third field in 18 weeks.

We then have $\begin{cases} \frac{10}3T+4g = 48x_1 \\10T + 9g = 21 \cdot 9x_1 \\ 24T+18g = 18x \cdot x_1 \end{cases}$.

Is this correct? And if so how should I solve it or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Let's see: if the fields were being left empty, then the amount of grass in each field is $(d+gt)A_i$, where $d$ and $g$ are unknown constants. Also the cows eat at a rate $c$ which is another unknown constant. So you have $\frac{10}{3}(d+4g)=48c,10(d+9g)=189c$. You then want $n$ such that $24(d+18g)=18nc$. So what you've written is not quite right because the amount of grass that grows in a given field scales with the size of the field.

Comment: So if we have 2 acres the grass will grow twice as fast?

Comment: Yes, your $g$ is new grass/week/acre, so the coefficients $4,9,18$ should be multiplied by the areas of the fields.  Then you have three equations in four unknowns, but everything scales so you can divide one out.  If you just plug along with substitution it will work out for your.

Comment: Newton's *Algebra* has a cows eating field problem.

Comment: You have $\frac{10}{3}(d+4g)=48c$ and $10(d+9g)=189c$. As Ross Millikan suggested, introduce $\delta=\frac{d}{c}$ and $\gamma=\frac{g}{c}$ and you get $\frac{10}{3}(\delta+4\gamma)=48$ and $10(\delta+9\gamma)=189$. This has a unique solution, and $n$ only depends on $\delta$ and $\gamma$, not on $d,g,c$ separately. (There is nothing magical going on with my choice of Greek letters, choose variable names as you see fit.)

Comment: Is the answer $50$

Comment: No, it is $36$.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: Rather late in the year(s), but hope you enjoy the non-algebraic solution !$\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-algebraic way,
using the unit cow-weeks (c-w) like man-days, and realizing that
c-w will be directly proportional to acreage

Initially, I shall transform figures to compute for $\frac{10}3$ acres

- Fodder needed for $4$ weeks  $=12\cdot4 = 48\;$ c-w
- Fodder needed for $9$ weeks $=\frac13\cdot21\cdot9 = 63\;$ c-w
- Fodder growth in $5$ weeks $=63-48 = 15\;$ c-w
- $\therefore$ Fodder growth in $9$ weeks $= 27\;$ c-w
- Fodder needed for $18$ weeks $= 63+27 =90\;$ c-w
- For $24$ acre field, enough fodder for $90\cdot24\div\frac{10}3= \color{red}{36}\cdot18\;$ c-w
- *Thus $\color{red}{36}$ cows can be fed*